# CMOS Camera Module - Question regarding power supply

Tags: power, voltage-regulator

I have a question regarding the choice of some components for a CMOS camera module.

The camera IC is the OV7670. The module PCB contains a pin header and power regulation circuitry to convert 3V3 voltage to 2V8 and 1V8, required by the OV7670.

My question is why are the two 10 ohm resistors, R1 and R2. Are they used just so there are two separate paths for AVDD and DOVDD? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Looks like the 10 ohm resistors are for RC filtering of noise.

Comment: Agreed, they provide a little isolation and filtering with those larger caps. Presumably the current draw of the parts is small.

Answer (score 1):

The 10-ohm resistors and 4.7uF capacitors form low pass filters for the power to the image sensor chip.  Some people use ferrite beads or inductors for the same purpose, depending on the chips' sensitivity to noise and possible noise characteristics on the input voltage.  Image sensors are highly noise-dependent, showing up as visible noise on the captured images.

This is a single-pole filter, with -3dB point at around 3kHz.  This is well below the typical switching power supply frequency range of 600kHz-2MHz but will not be effective on AC main noise (50/60Hz).

Series resistors are also helpful in monitoring current usage during circuit board debug, although much lower values can be used to lower the power loss.